# How to match and combine two Table-valued Functions

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two table-functions.

First Functions: It calculates the prices between the two dates entered. `[vkodu]` says what prices it will check.

```
USE [villapaket1]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fiyathesapla]    Script Date: 27.10.2020 15:42:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[fiyathesapla](@StartDate datetime2(5),@EndDate datetime2(5),@kodu nvarchar(max))
returns table
as
return (

WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     )
SELECT SUM( v_period.fiyat-((v_period.fiyat/100)*v_period.indirim)) as fiyat, v_period.vkodu as kodu  FROM theDates,v_period  WHERE tarih1<=theDates.theDate and tarih2>=theDates.theDate  and  vkodu=@kodu group by v_period.vkodu
)
```

Second Function: The `[vkodu]` of the buildings that are empty according to the dates entered return.

```
USE [villapaket1]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[FN_bos_tarihler]    Script Date: 27.10.2020 15:45:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[FN_bos_tarihler](@tarih1 datetime2(5),@tarih2 datetime2(5),@kapasite int)
Returns Table
As
Return
(
select kodu from  v_genel sub WHERE kodu NOT IN (SELECT rez_genel.vkodu FROM rez_genel WHERE ((tarih1<=@tarih1 and tarih2>=@tarih2)) and rez_genel.durumu = 'Onaylı')
and kodu NOT IN (SELECT rez_genel.vkodu FROM rez_genel WHERE ((tarih1>=@tarih1 and tarih2<=@tarih2)) and rez_genel.durumu = 'Onaylı')
and kodu NOT IN (SELECT rez_genel.vkodu FROM rez_genel WHERE ((tarih1>=@tarih1 and tarih2<=@tarih2)) and rez_genel.durumu = 'Onaylı')
and kodu NOT IN (SELECT rez_genel.vkodu FROM rez_genel WHERE ((tarih1>=@tarih1 and tarih1<=@tarih2)) and rez_genel.durumu = 'Onaylı')
and kodu NOT IN (SELECT rez_genel.vkodu FROM rez_genel WHERE ((tarih2>=@tarih1 and tarih2<=@tarih2)) and rez_genel.durumu = 'Onaylı')
and kodu NOT IN (SELECT v_genel.kodu FROM v_genel where durumu='0')
and  kodu NOT IN (SELECT kodu from v_genel where kapasite<@kapasite)
)
```

I want [vkodu] returned in the second function to match the first function and return the two tables as a single table.

```
SELECT kodu FROM FN_bos_tarihler('2020.11.01','2020.11.05',4)

SELECT kodu,fiyat FROM fiyathesapla('2020.11.01','2020.11.05','#VA7730')
```

[You can see the tables in the picture.][image: 1]

I want to combine the two functions by matching them. The dates will be entered by me, but `[vcode]` must match and only one table should return. There must be `[vkodu]` and `[fiyat] (calculated price)` in the return table.

Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  kodu
FROM
  FN_bos_tarihler('2020.11.01', '2020.11.05', 4) tt
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      kodu,
      fiyat
    FROM
      fiyathesapla('2020.11.01', '2020.11.05', tt.kodu)
  ) ttt
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

I am getting the error I tried to fix it. I could not be successful.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.   I am getting the error

Comment: @IsmailÇetin second statement needed an alias as well.

Comment: @Ismail Çetin, Just remove the last ')' it is a typo

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini no , It's not a typo

Comment: @eshirvana your code worked with me fine. so might be the date format need to be changed to '2020-11-15' rather than '2020.11.15' (it worked regardless of the results, I mean it worked in term f syntax )